# Group by multiple time units in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that consists of a time series data with 15-second intervals:

```
date_time             value    
2012-12-28 11:11:00   103.2
2012-12-28 11:11:15   103.1
2012-12-28 11:11:30   103.4
2012-12-28 11:11:45   103.5
2012-12-28 11:12:00   103.3
```

The data spans many years. I would like to group by both year and time to look at the distribution of time-of-day effect over many years. For example, I may want to compute the mean and standard deviation of every 15-second interval across days, and look at how the means and standard deviations change from 2010, 2011, 2012, etc. I naively tried `data.groupby(lambda x: [x.year, x.time])` but it didn't work. How can I do such grouping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case `date_time` is not your index, a `date_time`-indexed DataFrame could be created with:

```
dfts = df.set_index('date_time')
```

From there you can group by intervals using

```
dfts.groupby(lambda x : x.month).mean()
```

to see mean values for each month. Similarly, you can do

```
dfts.groupby(lambda x : x.year).std()
```

for standard deviations across the years.

If I understood the example task you would like to achieve, you could simply split the data into years using `xs`, group them and concatenate the results and store this in a new `DataFrame`.

```
years = range(2012, 2015)
yearly_month_stats = [dfts.xs(str(year)).groupby(lambda x : x.month).mean() for year in years]
df2 = pd.concat(yearly_month_stats, axis=1, keys = years)
```

From which you get something like

```
        2012       2013       2014
       value      value      value
1        NaN   5.324165  15.747767
2        NaN -23.193429   9.193217
3        NaN -14.144287  23.896030
4        NaN -21.877975  16.310195
5        NaN  -3.079910  -6.093905
6        NaN  -2.106847 -23.253183
7        NaN  10.644636   6.542562
8        NaN  -9.763087  14.335956
9        NaN  -3.529646   2.607973
10       NaN -18.633832   0.083575
11       NaN  10.297902  14.059286
12  33.95442  13.692435  22.293245
```

Answer (score 4):

You were close:

```
data.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.time])
```

Also be sure to set `date_time` as the index, as in [kermit666](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544059/kermit666)'s answer